# What template engines are there that allow creating templates in Microsoft Word?

Tags: c#, .net, templates, ms-word, template-engine

In a project I'm working on we will (most likely) need the following feature: the user uploads a word document (can be limited to DOCX, I believe), that is a template with placeholders. The system then takes this document, fills in the placeholders with data, and produces a final word document (and optionally also converts it to a PDF).

In the worst case I can dig through the bowels of DOCX myself, we did this with XLSX in another project (using the low-level library Microsoft provides), but it was quite painful, and I wonder if there is something premade.

**Added:** Completely forgot - we're working in Visual Studio 2012, C# 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned what languages/platform you are using which will certainly impact the range of solutions available to you.  [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) is a document engine which you can feed templates (doc,docx,odt) with placeholders and produce documents in a variety of formats (doc,docx,pdf,rtf,odt).  There is a java library version as well as a REST-based api version.  Please note I work for the company that created Docmosis.

Another option may be [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Oops, sorry. Slipped my mind. It's C# 4.5 - I've updated the question.

Comment: Good stuff. Both JODReports and Docmosis have C# interface options.

Answer (score 0):

There is any number of pre-existing solutions; you might try Googling "c# document assembly OR automation"

A couple of things to consider:

- who will be authoring the templates?  You might want an easy to use authoring tool
- might the document contain conditional text, or repeating stuff (eg table rows)

These systems work in different ways, including magic strings in the document, Word fields, and content controls.  I personally favour using content controls.

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress has a Rich Text Editor which it has almost all the capabilities of Microsoft Word.
we have used that in the same scenario and it was a lot easier than working with Microsoft Word.

Take a look at [THIS](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Rich_Editor/).